# WebSQL error `SQL execution is disallowed` when chaining promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, web-sql

I know the title is a mouthful but I honestly couldn't come up with a better one for my specific case (open to suggestions).
So basically I jotted down on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/k7sr39kg/) (a simplified version of) the issue I am facing. I am using AngularJS's `$q.all` method to collect an array of promises dependent on query results:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    $q.all(fn(tx)).then(function(a) {
        console.log("Result:", a);
    });
});
```

where `fn` is a function that returns an array of promises.
In the above case, everything works as expected and the result (the array of sql query results which resolve the promises) is `console.log`ged correctly.
However, if I wrap `$q.all` in the `then` method of another deferred object, as so:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    fn2(tx).then(function(tx) {
        $q.all(fn(tx)).then(function(a) {
            console.log("Result:", a);
        });
    });
});
```

I get the error: `Error: Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction': SQL execution is disallowed.`
(`fn2` is a function that merely returns a promise which resolves to the `tx` object itself).
Have I stumbled upon a common pitfall? I searched about but haven't come up with anything. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the transaction is already getting closed when `fn2` is resolved.

If you don't use a transaction (or even the same one) in both `fn2` and `fn` it should work:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    fn2(tx).then(function(tx) {
        // new tranaction as the old one is closed
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            $q.all(fn(tx)).then(function(a) {
                console.log("Result:", a);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzo8g3at/).

Comment: Thank you. I see, but I don't understand the reason why the transaction should close when `fn2` is resolved. Besides, I mentioned this was a simplified example, but in my actual scenario `fn2` executes queries inside transaction `tx`; if I issue a new "nested" transaction as per your example and the sql executions in it for some reason fail, will the already-closed, old transaction rollback or has that already been committed? This is my main concern.

Comment: I guess my best option is to replace `$q.all(fn(tx))` with `$q.all(fn(tx, fn2))` and modify `fn` so it accepts a transaction and a function (or possibly any number thereof) and prepends `fn2`'s promise to the `promiseArray` used by `$q.all`, so there is no chaining and the process basically reverts to the first, working example.

Comment: that's just how WebSQL works. it's closing the transaction once it gets back to the event loop.. yeah i guess your solution should work that way

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/k7sr39kg/1/. I will go with my solution since the queries both inside `fn2` and inside `fn` must be executed in the **same** transaction, so that if any fails the whole transaction does, too. Thanks for your help!